# Delay start of consumer forces rebalance of group

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

We need to delay start of consumer.
Here's what we need:

1. Start consumer A (reading topic "xyz")
2. When consumer A will process all messages, we need to start consumer B (reading topic "zyx")

After reading this:
[How to find no more messages in kafka topic/partition & reading only after writing to topic is done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60656704/how-to-find-no-more-messages-in-kafka-topic-partition-reading-only-after-writi)

We set idleEventInterval on containerProperties of consumer A:

```
containerProperties.setIdleEventInterval(30000L);
```

and on consumer B:

```
container.setAutoStartup(false);
```

then we have:

```
@EventListener
public void handleListenerContainerIdleEvent(ListenerContainerIdleEvent event) {
    if(canStartContainer(event.getListenerId())) {
        Optional.ofNullable(containers.get("container-a"))
            .ifPresent(AbstractMessageListenerContainer::start);
    }
}
```

We found that it's exactly what we need - it works fine, but we faced one problem: when consumer B is starting, it forces rebalance of all other consumers.
Can we avoid it?

> Request joining group due to: group is already rebalancing
>
> Revoke previously assigned partitions
>
> (Re-)joining group

It's not a big issue, but we use ConsumerSeekAware to reset offset using seekToBeginning, so topic is read twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use the same `group.id` with consumers on different topics; it will cause an unnecessary rebalance, as you have found out.

Use different `group.id`s for consumers on different topics.